# How to properly format this Nested IF function in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, date

I'm trying to make a function have an output of 0 or 1 if cell B2 has any date with the format mm/dd/yyyy.

For example,

I have two columns. The first column is called "OUT" and the second column is called "AMOUNT OUT".
So what I'm trying to figure out is: what function can I use for the column that reads "OUT" if any cell
in that column has A DATE written inside of them--if they have a date--I need the function to output a `1` 
in "AMOUNT OUT". When it doesn't have a date, "AMOUNT OUT" should be `0`.

I tried writing this formula inside of "AMOUNT OUT" 
`=CONCATENATE(IF(B2="DATEVALUE()" , "1" , "0", )`
B2 CELL is the "OUT" cell.
              DATEVALUE didn't work because it asks for a specific date and I need it to be any date under the format mm/dd/yyyy.

Am I not using the right function?

Comment: It might be tricky with the built in functions.  I can think of a way that works for many dates, but when you have say `01/10/2017` it breaks (that could be Jan 10th, or Oct 1).  Is VBA an option?  Edit: Hm, with VBA too, it might be tricky. Again, how do you know if `01/10/2017`, or `04/06/2017` is `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`...

Comment: I appreciate the reply, VBA or not, I don't mind. Let me know if anything comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
If(ISERR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy")));"1";"0")
```

Explanation:

- `Text(B2, "mm/dd/yyyy")` - Only necessary if your values are actually dates, to convert them to strings (use your preferred format)
- `Datevalue(...)` - Converts a text to a date
- `Iserr(...)` - Checks if the value inside is an error (if the text is an invalid date, it's an error).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, although, when I input this function, it gives me the "There's a problem with this formula." error. I simply copied and pasted it, does that break it?

Comment: How will Excel know if the date is entered as `dd/mm/yyyy` for some dates, i.e. `10/03/2017`? That could be October 3rd, or 10th of March.

Comment: Probably a comma that I put instead of a semicolon? This message is usually a typo, a missing parentheses and things like that.

Comment: There is usually a fixed date pattern that is configured on your machine. If you're using an US excel in English, it will very probably be `mm/dd/yyyy`, if you're using a Brazilian excel in Portuguese you wil lhave `dd/mm/yyyy`. This depends not only on Excel configurations, but also on your Windows configuration.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Exactly what I wanted, all I had to do was just that, replace the semi-colon with a comma and it worked! Thank you.